# Containerized Django Migrations

Tags: django, amazon-ecs

What are the best practices for managing django schema/data migrations in a containerized deployment? We are having issues with multiple containers attempting to run the migrate command on deploy and running our migrations in parallel. I was surprised to learn that django doesn't coordinate this internally to prevent the migrations from being run by two containers at the same time. We are using AWS ECS and struggling to automatically identify one container as the master node from which to run our migrations.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this exact problem in the past, and I was also surprised to find that Django doesn't use a database lock to manage this like other DB migration tools do.

My solution (inspired by Terraform's state lock mechanism) was to create a DynamoDB table to use for distributed locks. I'm using boto3 to perform a write to the lock table, with a `ConditionExpression` that the lock doesn't already exist, (with a while loop to wait if the lock does exist), then I call the Django migrate command, then I delete the lock.

I bundled that logic into a Django management command, and the startup script in my docker image I deploy to ECS runs this command before it starts the Django app.